# Thread was being aborted on a delegate

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am getting this type of error on the below function:I have also handled it with ThreadException but still getting such an error:

```
private void tmrOneSec_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        tsSpendTime = tsSpendTime.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
        tsRemTime = tsTotalTime.Subtract(tsSpendTime);
        if (tsRemTime.Ticks > 0)
            clsCommonFunc.MultiThreadSetText(txtTimeRem, clsCommonFunc.GetFormattedTime(tsRemTime));
}


public static void MultiThreadSetText(TextBox TxtBox, string Text)
{

        if (TxtBox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            TxtBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                MultiThreadSetText(TxtBox, Text);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            TxtBox.Text = Text;
            TxtBox.Refresh();
        }
}
```

And the error is this:

```
Source :: mscorlib
Error :: 6/5/2012 8:51:28 AM
Error Description : Thread was being aborted.


Stack Trace:    at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(SafeWaitHandle waitHandle, UInt32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int64 timeout, Boolean exitContext)
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WaitForWaitHandle(WaitHandle waitHandle)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method)
at SE5.clsCommonFunc.MultiThreadSetText(TextBox TxtBox, String Text)
```

I am not able to recognize the exact problem.

Comment: You get the exception waiting for the return from the Invoke call. Try changing TxtBox.Invoke(...) to TxtBox.BeginInvoke(...). Does it help?

Comment: I'll turn that into an answer then if you don't mind, so you can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the exception waiting for the return from the `Invoke` call.

Try changing

```
TxtBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    MultiThreadSetText(TxtBox, Text);
});
```

to

```
TxtBox.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    MultiThreadSetText(TxtBox, Text);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your delegate usage like so:

```
private delegate void MultiThreadSetTextDelegate(TextBox TxtBox, string Text);

public static void MultiThreadSetText(TextBox TxtBox, string Text)
{

        if (TxtBox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            TxtBox.Invoke(new MultiThreadSetTextDelegate(MultiThreadSetText), TxtBox, Text);
        }
        else
        {
            TxtBox.Text = Text;
            TxtBox.Refresh();
        }
}
```

Try that, if you still have the error let me know.  But this is how I invoke my delegates and I have no troubles at all! :)